# Apple - Problem With Multiple Devices

Tags: clash-of-clans, game-center, the-sims-freeplay

I had an iPad, that I played on a lot. I want to play the same games on my iPhone.

#### Clash of Clans:

I did the tutorial on the iPhone. Then I connected to Facebook and Game Center. I can't upload the data to my iPhone, but I can upload the new data for iPad.

#### TheSims Freeplay:

I save my iPad data into my Cloud, but I can only find an old game progress.

I always have to log-in on my GameCenter in my iPhone. It can't detect, that I logged in. What seems the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Given that both are Apple-made/iOS units; for *Clash Of Clans*, it won't be that hard, as long as you are logged on to a Game Center account. Logging back in to that same account on other apple devices will automatically sync your game data. If you're seeing an old save, then you might be using an old back-up as well, make a new back up. Restoring save data from iCloud should help you through this  [link.](https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT204184) If you don't like restoring a *Sims Freeplay* save from iCloud, the game allows it to save data from server as said [here.](http://forums.supercheats.com/video-games/gaming-news/123644/iCloud-back-up-for-Sims-freepl.htm)